# Sorting a vector of structures based on one of the elements

Tags: c++, sorting, structure

I was writing a program to input the marks of `n` students in four subjects and then find the rank of one of them based on the total scores (from codeforces.com: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1017/A). I thought storing the marks in a structure would help keeping track of the various subjects.

Now, what I did is simply implement a bubble sort on the vector while checking the total value. I want to know, is there a way that I can sort the vector based on just one of the members of the struct using `std::sort()`? Also, how do we make it descending?

Here is what the code looks like right now:

```
//The Structure
struct scores
{
    int eng, ger, mat, his, tot, rank;
    bool tommyVal;
};

//The Sort (present inside the main function)
    bool sorted = false;
    while (!sorted)
    {
        sorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            if (stud[i].tot < stud[i + 1].tot)
            {
                std::swap(stud[i], stud[i + 1]);
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Just in case you're interested, I need to find the rank of a student named Thomas. So, for that, I set the value of tommyVal true for his element, while I set it as false for the others. This way, I can easily locate Thomas' marks even though his location in the vector has changed after sorting it based on their total marks.

Also nice to know that `std::swap()` works for swapping entire structs as well. I wonder what other data structures it can swap.

Comment: *I thought storing the marks in a structure would help keeping track of the various subjects.* Exactly the right idea. Writing bubblesort is not so good for two reasons: 1. don't write stuff unless you have to. There are library functions to do the sorting for you. 2. Usually the code competition sites are looking for fast code and bubblesort is about as slow as they come.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I had written std::swap instead of std::sort int the first paragraph. Rectified the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::sort()` allows you to give it a predicate so you can perform comparisons however you want, eg:

```
std::sort(
  stud.begin(),
  stud.begin()+n, // <-- use stud.end() instead if n == stud.size() ...
  [](const scores &a, const scores &b){ return a.tot < b.tot; }
);
```

Simply use `return b.tot < a.tot` to reverse the sorting order.